# dt in the Kalman Filter

Tags: kalman-filter

I'm a dummy for Kalman Filter. My question is about dt in the prediction step of Kalman Filter. After initialization of Kalman Filters using covariance matrix and some uncertainty stuff, predict function generally takes the dt as an input, but filterpy implementation doesn't take the dt as an input. It confused me that kalman filter has to take dt in the prediction step or not. Here is the filterpy implementation:
https://github.com/rlabbe/filterpy/blob/master/filterpy/kalman/kalman_filter.py . Also, I'm not sure that maybe the user updates the transition matrix before calling the prediction function.

Answer (score 0):

F is notation used for discrete transition matrix so it involves dt already and is seen in the example code given in the link you have provided. Your assumtions are correct if dt is not const F should be recalculated before calling predict ( in this particualar example ). Sometimes dt can be const and if model is linear F can be calculated only once at filter init stage